# hbm2java 3 - can't find Mapping class

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-plugin, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I use the plugin below to generate my Entity classes.
When I execute command mvn hibernate3:hbm2java I did get this error:

There was an error creating the AntRun task.: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/Mapping: org.hibernate.engine.Mapping

I did try every hibernate version but I can't find the one that contains indicated class.

Edit: JDK 11 is used.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-entities</id>
            <phase>post-clean</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>hbm2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <hibernatetool destdir="${project.build.sourceDirectory}">
            <classpath>
                <path location="${project.build.sourceDirectory}/classes"/>
            </classpath>
            <!--<configuration configurationfile="src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml"/> -->
            <jdbcconfiguration
                    packagename="com.cm.sourcegenerator"
                    revengfile="src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.reveng.xml"
            />
            <hbm2java jdk5="true" ejb3="true"/>
            <!--<hbm2cfgxml ejb3="true" destdir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate" /> -->

        </hibernatetool>

    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Mapping interface was removed in Hibernate 4 and later versions. Instead, you can use the MetadataImplementor interface to access the metadata of your entities.

Since you are using Hibernate 4.3.11. Final, you can try changing your hibernate3-maven-plugin configuration to use the MetadataSources tool instead of HibernateTool. You can do this by replacing your current  configuration with:

```java
<metadataSources destdir="${project.build.sourceDirectory}">
    <classpath>
        <path location="${project.build.sourceDirectory}/classes"/>
    </classpath>
    <configuration>
        <jdbc-connection>
            <!-- your database connection details here -->
        </jdbc-connection>
        <hibernate-mapping package="com.cm.sourcegenerator">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate">
                <include name="**/*.hbm.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </hibernate-mapping>
    </configuration>
</metadataSources>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answare. But if i replace your code at place of hibernatetool, intelliJ show me error on configuration. I didn't find documentation. Can you explain in details? Which are tag for connection to db? I forgot, i can use Hibernate 5 because sdk version is 11.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the new version of the tool and everything works fine

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.properties</propertyFile>
        <revengFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.reveng.xml</revengFile>
        <ejb3>true</ejb3>
        <jdk5>true</jdk5>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <packageName>com.cm.sourcegenerator.entity</packageName>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- DB Driver of your database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: how to run this maven pom? I try hibernate5:hbm2java and fail